# How to convert Mutual User Relationship to Reciprocal?

Tags: 7, users

I had a relationship set up on my website (let's call it "Friends"), and many of my users have used it. It was a Mutual relationship. That relationship is being used to provide access to the user's nodes via Panels... for example, if User A and User B become friends, then User A can see User B's nodes, and User B can see User A's nodes.

I recently converted the (mutual) Friends relationship to One Way with the possibility of Reciprocation, because I now need to allow User A to request access to User B's nodes without giving User B access to User A's nodes. If User B then decides to request access to User A's nodes, they can do so because of the reciprocation setting.

That functionality is working fine for any new Friends. The problem I am having is that any Friend relationships that existed before the relationship was changed from Mutual to One Way/Recip are not acting like reciprocated relationships; they are acting like One Way relationships. Therefore, if User A was the one who requested the original mutual Friend relationship, they now own the One-Way relationship with User B, and User B does not own a reciprocal relationship with User A.

I need for the formerly Mutual Friend relationships to now be One Way with Reciprocation. How can I do this? Is there a way for me to edit it in the database perhaps? I definitely cannot ask all of the users to un-friend and re-friend their existing relationships.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue... I had to update the Relationship IDs in the database for the originally-Mutual relationships because they shared the same RID, thus making each RID unique. The one-way/reciprocal relationships do not/cannot share the same RID.